# Lazy loading property that is JsonConvert.DeserializeObject of another property

Tags: c#, .net-core, json.net

I am setting up an application that is using EF Core paired with PostgreSQL using the npgsql driver.  I am utilizing the [jsonb] field type in PostgreSQL, but it only maps back to a string property in my data model.

```
public class MyModel
{
     [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
     public string JsonData { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to access the JsonData field as a Dictionary property.  The code below works, but feels wasteful to me as the JsonDataDictionary is re-built every time it is accessed (caching).

```
public class MyModel
{
     [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
     public string JsonData { get; set; }

     public Dictionary<string,string> JsonDataDictionary
     {
        get
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(JsonData);
        }
     }
}
```

I could store the deserialized object the first time and then return that each time.  But... it is possible that the JsonData property changes and so the dictionary needs to be re-built.

```
public class MyModel
{
     [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
     public string JsonData { get; set; }

     private Dictionary<string,string> JsonDataDictionary; 
     public Dictionary<string,string> JsonDataDictionary
     {
        get
        {
            if (_JsonDataDictionary == null)
            {
                 _JsonDataDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(JsonData);
            }

            return _JsonDataDictionary;
        }
     }
}
```

I thought about using some sort of flag to track the "dirty-ness" of the JsonData property, but something about this doesn't look best practice.

```
public class MyModel
{
    private string _JsonData;
    private bool _JsonDataChanged = true;

    [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
    public string JsonData
    {
        get
        {
            return _JsonData;
        }
        set
        {
            _JsonData = value;
            _JsonDataChanged = true;
        }
    }

    private Dictionary<string,string> _JsonDataDictionary;

    [NotMapped]
    public Dictionary<string,string> JsonDataDictionary
    {
        get
        {
            if (_JsonDataDictionary == null || _JsonDataChanged)
            {
                _JsonDataDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(_JsonData);
                _JsonDataChanged = false;
            }

            return _JsonDataDictionary;
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone know of a better way to do this?

GOALS: Not running deserialize every time dictionary is called. Wasting as few cycles as possible. Realizing that EF Core caches a bunch of these objects sometimes, so I only want dictionary objects lazy loaded at the time of their first access (or when JsonData string changes.)

I have read up Lazy initialization, but because the JsonDataDictionary relies on the JsonData string, I don't think the static nature of Lazy will work. See:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/performance/lazy-initialization

Comment: I'm curious why your instance of your `MyModel` class wouldn't just get completely recreated when the JSON changes? Either way, this is really an opinion based question, not suited to the type of posts that are on topic on Stack Overflow. You *might* get better responses on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (but check their rules first)

Comment: Interesting thing is that trying to debug the final version of this code, Visual Studio always shows JsonDataDictionary as being instantiated.  But I was able to create some test code that shows that the internal dictionary field is only being updated when first accessed or when the string JsonData changes.  https://github.com/tgourley/csharp-lazy-load-property